# Does HTTPS protect against CSRF attacks?

Tags: asp.net, security, csrf

I'm writing a mostly ajax-driven web application and I'm looking at how to protect the user from CSRF attacks. I'm planning to run the pages of the application where the user is logged in to do his work in HTTPS mode.

Does running the page on HTTPS work to protect against CSRF attacks?

Comment: It's CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) not CSFR

Comment: Remember to [start with a little bit of research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) as to what causes said vulnerability.

Comment: How is this related to `asp.net`? `CSRF` is a platform/server independent vulnerability.

Comment: Related: [anti-CSRF tokens in HTTPS environment](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/10549/41545)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, running a page on HTTPS does not protect it from CSRF. The fact that the communications between the browser and server is encrypted has no bearing on CSRF.

I suggest reading the OWASP guidance on [preventing CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: What's your recommendation for securing ajax transactions? Form submission seems well documented but ajax much less so.

Comment: @frenchie - Pretty  much everything that applies to form submissions applies to ajax, as well as XSS.

Comment: Form submission talks about passing a token in the form, using viewstate for instance. That doesn't work with $.ajax

Comment: @frenchie - You can pass a token with the data in ajax. If you are passing JSON along for example.

Comment: Can you please explain? Linking without context is discouraged - stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

A general, golden rule woule be:

*Never trust that the incoming client request is a legitimate one. Be always suspicious and assume that the request could be maliciously forged.*

Few specific rules beyond the mentioned OWASP article:

1. if your data needs authentication/authorization, avoid generic interfaces on the server, like the CRUD interface. easy to code, difficult to authorize specific requests coming from clients. instead, offer a SOA-style interface with explicit methods dedicated to specific use cases where you will have direct control over requests and their parameters.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954638.aspx
2. even if the framework provides some control over the request validity (ASP.NET viewstate), check again if the user is authorized to pass the set of incoming parameters.

Comment: The viewstate? My request are going to the page with $.ajax so I can't use the viewstate's data for a postback.

Comment: This was only an example of specific validation mechanism.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain:

• HTTPS prevents from someone on the same network to get your Session KEY/ID. Say they got your session identification key/id, then they can fake your IP if needed and send all POST requests they want back to server.
With HTTPS all HTTP body (the whole "HTML") is encrypted. Hence no session key is being guessed.

• What happens in CSRF is that the user is clicks a link, which also creates a request to another server and communicates with it, say using user's session but NOT ON THE SAME NETWORK. Means that it cannot listen to what the server replies back to user. If the attacker knows the replies and can communicate them, voila. No problem. No money's left on the user account. But if the server sends a random token to the IP associated with the session, then the attacker cannot guess it on a different network!

Answer (score 1):

The best possible solution is to include secret tokens - to identify the user - in form submissions to the server. Refer to the following links for more information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html

http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/csrf/

Answer (score 0):

https doesn't safeguard your app from xss attacks. You need csrf token which should be (1) encrypted (2) expiring after some time (3) CSRF  token based on page & time